# Use xmlstarlet in bash script to link xml nodes and extract elements

Tags: xml, bash, shell, scripting, xmlstarlet

I am fairly familiar with XML but I've never had to delve into the complexities, and I'm a novice with XSL, XPATH, and with XMLSTARLET. I need a shell script that will extract a simple list from XML files which follow this kind of format..

```xml
<tv>
  <channel id="ffd49fe9acd778774b4933e10b6afb75">
    <display-name>ITV</display-name>
  </channel>
  <channel id="398fe9bc5ee3b47556d06f9b9cb95562">
    <display-name>BBC One</display-name>
  </channel>
  <channel id="3932fa4d11310596e0c3eba7dc8caf4c">
    <display-name>Channel 4</display-name>
  </channel>
  <programme channel="398fe9bc5ee3b47556d06f9b9cb95562">
    <title>Pointless</title>
  </programme>
  <programme channel="ffd49fe9acd778774b4933e10b6afb75">
    <title>The Chase</title>
  </programme>
  <programme channel="398fe9bc5ee3b47556d06f9b9cb95562">
    <title>BBC News</title>
  </programme>
  <programme channel="3932fa4d11310596e0c3eba7dc8caf4c">
    <title>Naked Attraction</title>
  </programme>
</tv>
```

I picked up xmlstarlet (I'm using Cygwin) and I'm easily able to produce a list of channels or a list of programmes, but linking them together is beyond me although I've done a LOT of Googling.

```
#List of channels
xmlstarlet sel -t -m /tv/channel -v display-name -n

#List of Programmes
xmlstarlet sel -t -m /tv/programme -v title -n

#Filter a particular channel
sel -t -m "tv" -v 'channel[@id="398fe9bc5ee3b47556d06f9b9cb95562"]/display-name'  -n
```

It would seem to me a simple thing to replace the square brackets in the last statement with something like [@id=programme/@channel] but it seems xpath doesn't work like that. I'm looking for results like this..

```
Pointless, BBC One
The Chase, ITV
BBC News, BBC One
Naked Attraction, Channel 4
```

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to circumvent the context would be to store the matching channel in a variable:

```sh
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '/tv/programme' --var ch='@channel' -v 'title' \
  -v '", "' -v '/tv/channel[@id=$ch]/display-name' -n
```

```
Pointless, BBC One
The Chase, ITV
BBC News, BBC One
Naked Attraction, Channel 4
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I had been trying to make use of variables but couldn't figure it out and it didn't seem well documented. Although your answer does work on my sample, when applied to the real data it just hangs. I had tried similar things referencing /tv/channel[] but it always hung. Bearing in mind there are over 200,000 programmes in the real data. I'll figure out if there's an issue in the data itself and scratch my head some more.

Comment: @Stocko Does your big file have any elements (outside the ones of the sample) that might interfere structurally? Does the file entirely fit into the memory on the machine you're working on? Did you consider trying out (or even eventually using) other tools to cross-test your observations? Off the top of my head, `xq` would be another CLI tool (implementations exist in [python](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) (packaged together with another tool called `yq`) and in [go](https://github.com/syui/xq)). Or try a full-featured industry-standard XQuery processor: [saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net).

Comment: @Stocko Using (python's) `xq`, the solution from above would read: `xq -r '.tv | JOIN(INDEX(.channel[]; ."@id"); .programme[]; ."@channel"; .[0].title + ", " + .[1]."display-name")'`